# How to Implement CRUD using Entity Framework Core TPT Inheritance with SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Given the following...

Here is my object model:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person() { }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public String FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public String MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public String LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class JobApplicant : Person
{
    public JobApplicant() { }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public Employee() { }
}
```

Here is what i have in my DbContext:

```
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set;}

public DbSet<JobApplicant> JobApplicants { get; set; }

public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

var person = mb.Entity<Person>();
person.HasKey(aa => aa.PersonId);
```

Here is the short version of what i'm doing in my web api function:

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
newEmployee.PersonId = "Guid value here";
db.Employees.Add(newEmployee);
db.SaveChanges();
```

In the database I have a `Person`, `JobApplicant`, and `Employee` table. `Person` table has a `PersonId` as PK. `Employee` and `JobApplicant` each have a `PersonId` field that is both the primary key of their table as well as a FK to the `Person` table. This is what EF generated via the migration using the Code First approach.

The scenario is that the person I am trying to add as an Employee already exists in the Person table because they were added to it via a `JobApplicant` but they do not already exist in the Employee table and I am trying to insert a record for them into the Employee table but with all this in place I currently get the following error when executing `db.SaveChanges()`:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Person'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Person'. The duplicate key value is (f73190f2-d766-4199-9dcd-2831c0844141).

What is the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: You can't have different `Person` objects with the same `PersonId` value. The person with the id in your question, is it a job applicant or an employee? It can't be both.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your response a little? Why do you say it can't be both? I understand that from a database perspective two seperate Person entities cannot have the same primary key but that is not my intention here. Using my example, a Person starts out as a JobApplicant before they become an Employee but all their JobApplicant related data does not go away once they become an Employee. Are you saying that the principle of inheritance dictates that one base type entity cannot exist as more than one type of derived type?

Comment: The problem is how you want to model your business requirement in C#, regardless of how the data will be stored? "Usually" you are either a `JobApplicant` or you get hired to be an `Employee`. You have modeled the `Person` class that way. Please [edit] your question to include the C# code only, how you want to model your business rules, but only from the view port of C#. There might be other ways to model what you are trying to do like having a `JobApplicantData` and `Employee` (nullable) property in the `Person` entity. There are several other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, using inheritance, the real identities are the JobApplicant and the Employee.  The Person entity is simply a convenience for storing similar information that can exist in a JobApplicant **or** an Employee.

I think you need to consider Person to be a unique identity in itself and use a relationship, instead of inheritance.

```
public class Person
{
    public Person() { }

    public Guid PersonId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public String FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public String MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public String LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class JobApplicant
{
    public JobApplicant() { }

    public Guid JobApplicationId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Person PersonalInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Employee() { }

    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Person PersonalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use the same Person (PeronalInfo) in both the JobApplicant and Employee.

Comment: Neil, I may end up trying this solution. I'm curious as to why you propose going this route though. Part of the same question I asked Progman. Does the principle of inheritance dictate that a base type cannot exist as more than one derived type? Or, is this more a limitation with entity framework? If i was not using entity framework I could overcome my issue easily. Also, generally speaking i would want my derived types to "inherit" my base classes business rules to and i don't know off the top of my head if that is easily done using the approach you propose. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct about the principle of inheritance.  The base class DEFINITION is a blueprint to store similar data / functionality that may be applicable to any number of derived class DEFINITIONS.  However an object INSTANCE of that base class can only be used in the context of one derived object INSTANCE.  I may have a blueprint for a bathroom that can be re-used in many different house styles, but 2 different built houses can't actually share one bathroom (there needs to be 2 builds of the bathroom, one for each house).